# drawRect not getting called for UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIImageView in my IB and I created a subclass of UIImageView with one method drawRect:

```
@implementation UIImageViewLine

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"CALLED");
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0); 
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}

@end
```

I have changed the class of the UIImageView to this subclass, however the drawRect is never called. Any idea why?

Comment: why subclass UIImageView not UIView?

Comment: well so I have to subclass a UIView and not UIImageView? What if I want to draw a line on a UIImageView, how can I do that?

Comment: you can draw on UIImage and use UIImageView to display the image

Comment: You can give your image view a non-opaque subview, and use the subview to draw the line.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `UIImageView` doesn't call `drawRect` when subclassed.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2):

> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView will not call drawRect: a subclass. If your subclass needs custom drawing code, it is recommended you use UIView as the base class.

You can simply replace the `UIImageView` by a normal `UIView` and draw the image and your custom drawings in the `UIView`'s `drawRect` method or in child layers.

Comment: That's why I love SO, I guess this just saved me half an hour

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sch's answer, it is worth noting how UIImageView can be used differently to UIView.

The approach with ImageView is that you change its .image property. This means that the image is cached on the view stack. If the image changes every frame, then this doesn't give you much. But if it doesn't, it is a considerable improvement. In most games/apps most objects don't change every frame.

You can change the location, rotation, and opacity of the UIView through calls to the underlying CALayer. This is just a change to a transformation matrix so incurs little/no time penalty.

I strongly recommend that anybody making real time 2D graphics who isn't familiar with this argument reads https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1708/_index.html which explains the argument much better and gives sample code. It is surprisingly simple to do.

The idea of wrapping your game object in a UIImageView seems counterintuitive, because you wan't to separate the game logic from the presentation level and this binds them together. However, having just modded my game prototype according to Apple's recommendation, I'm getting double the frame rate, so I'm very willing to compromise my architectural purity.