# Why I the drawRect method which override on category of UIIMageView doesn't called

Tags: ios, overriding, categories

I override the method drawRect of category in the category. But it seems didn't called.
What's the matter?

I init the view with initWithFrame.

Comment: i have to ask this, did you add your category header `.h`? perhaps you should share releated parts of your category class otherwise it's too hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: [This article tells you how to fix this problem](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html).

Comment: @Amourreux I find a answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9405153/1130175 
UIImageView will not call drawrect, because it draws its images to the display.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9405153/1130175

Above is an answer for this question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you, I think I find the reason.